# Variable contador con python y html

Tags: html, python

La idea es usar una variable contador para que el bucle for se aplique de manera diferente según el valor de la variable, pero no logro modificar el valor de la variable en el fichero html. Tener en cuenta que ya mandé la variable contador a este fichero; también ya se cerró el: `<ul>` que se ve en la pregunta, solo se ha puesto aquí incompleto.

```html
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for torneo in todo_t %}
        {% if contador == 0 %}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class= "display-4 text-center mt-4 titulo">PRIMER LUGAR: {{torneo["usuario"]}}, PUNTAJE: {{torneo["suma"]}}</span>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if contador == 1 %}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class= "display-4 text-center mt-4 titulo">SEGUNDO LUNGAR: {{torneo["usuario"]}}, PUNTAJE: {{torneo["suma"]}}</span>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if contador == 2 %}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class= "display-4 text-center mt-4 titulo">TERCER LUNGAR: {{torneo["usuario"]}}, PUNTAJE: {{torneo["suma"]}}</span>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        { contador = contador + 1 }
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota: como no se aclara que modulo para renderizar plantillas html se está usando, voy a, juzgando la sintaxis, asumir que se trata de [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/).

---

##### Abordando la problematica original

Nota: la información sale de [esta respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72249038/12913664)

Lamentablemente, hacer un contador dentro de jinja no es tan sencillo como lo harías en Python.

A primera vista, la sintaxis sería `{% set variable = valor %}`, siendo el prefijo set el que hace esto posible.
Sin embargo, hay una diferencia entre Python y jinja, la cual es que el interior del bucle for tiene su propio [ambito de variables](https://www2.eii.uva.es/fund_inf/cpp/temas/2_tipos_variables/ambito_variables.html). No profundizaré en esto para evitar extenderme demasiado, pero digamos que es como si lo que está dentro del bucle estubiera dentro de una función.

Esto tendría de efecto que el contador no incremente, debido a que en realidad creamos dos variables contador separadas.

Por lo tanto, debemos usar un espacio de nombres:

```
<ul>
    {% set ns = namespace(contador=0) %} 

    {% for _ in "abcd" %}
        <li>{{ns.contador}}<li>
        {% set ns.contador = ns.contador + 1 %}
    {% endfor %}
<ul>
```

Solucionando así el problema planteado. Sin embargo hay...

##### Mejores alternativas

Python nos permite crear un contador automatico. Esta función magica se llama
[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), que toma un iterable, el valor inicial del contador (por default 0) y, al iterar sobre el resultado de la llamada, va devolviendo tuplas del estilo `(contador, valor)`, la cual podemos desempaquetar, quedandonos un bucle for del estilo `{% for contador, valor in enumerate(iterable) %}`

Pero, si en realidad, la idea es hacer una lista con un ranking como se ve en la plantilla de la pregunta, hay algo aun mejor que hacer varios ifs dependiendo del valor del contador. Tal como vas, vas a conseguir un código repetitivo y dificil de leer.

Podemos repensar el programa así:

Tenemos una lista de lugares:

```
["Primer", "Segundo", "tercero"]
```

Y una lista de usuarios ordenada por su lugar en el ranking

```
["juan", "felipe", "carlos"]
```

Entonces, el usuario n-esimo de la lista de usuarios corresponderá al lugar n-esimo de la lista de lugares. Listo, armamos el bucle for:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader

string = (
"""
<ul> 
    {% for i in range(len(usuarios)) %}
        {% set usuario = usuarios[i] %}
        {% set lugar = lugares[i] %}

        <ul>{{lugar}} LUGAR: {{usuario}}</ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
"""
)

template = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(string)

# La función len no existe en jinja, se la pasamos al scope
print(template.render(usuarios=["juan", "felipe", "carlos"], lugares=["PRIMER", "SEGUNDO", "TERCER"], len=len))
```

Ten en cuenta que esto dará error si no hay suficientes lugares en la lista para todos los usuarios.

También se puede usar [zip](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#zip) para iterar en paralelo (también hay que pasarla como hice con len). Cito de la documentación: `Iterar sobre varios iterables en paralelo, generando tuplas con un item para cada una.` y podemos desempaquetar esa tupla igual que con enumerate.

Ten en cuenta que la iteración con zip se detiene cuando alguno de los dos iterables se termina. Es decir, no va a mostrar usuarios más allá de la cantidad de lugares en la lista.

##### Consejos adicionales

- Considero que, si vas a hacer un ranking complejo, es más facil hacer un numerito seguido de `°` (1°, 2°, 3°) para representar cada puesto. Las reglas usadas para armar los números ordinales dependen de las cifras del número en cuestión. Cosa que no pasa con la otra tecnica.
- Cuando escribes código repetitivo, suele ser buena idea simplificarlo. Esto creando funciones, bucles, etc.